# Finite Modules Isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Two vector spaces are isomorphic if and only if they have the same dimension.
In particular, two vector spaces over a finite field are isomorphic if and only if they have the same cardinality.
For a general ring $R$, I think it is not true that two $R$-modules are isomorphic if they have the same cardinality.
I would like to have some example of that with a finite ring $R$, so I can have a better picture of the situation.

> Thus, I am looking for examples of the following.
>
> 1. A finite ring $R$ and two $R$-modules $M$ and $N$ of the same finite cardinality such that $M \ncong N$.
> 2. A similar example where $M$ and $N$ are moreover isomorphic as abelian groups.

Comment: Are they supposed to be free modules?

Comment: Modules with finite set structure of same cardinality? Finite type modules with the same cardinality of generating systems?

Comment: @Jose27 I dont have any condition, i gues the modules can be free or not.

Comment: @Eoin Modules with finite set structure of same cardinality

Comment: @Dimitri Recall that vector spaces of equal cardinality of basis are isomorphic, not just vector spaces of equal cardinality! That said, I think Eoin has a point : are you sure what you want to ask is not examples of finitely generated modules of same number of generators which are not isomorphic?

Comment: @BalarkaSen i know, but in the case of vector spaces over finite fields its the same.
I am asking for 2 finite modules $A_1, A_2$ over a finite ring R such that $|A_1|=|A_2|$ but $A_1$ and $A_2$ are not isomorphic.

Comment: Thanks @user254022 that's right but i was thinking in 2 modules that have the same group structure, but i guess i forget that part when i edited the original question to make it more simple.

Comment: I have removed my earlier comments and added them as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Any abelian group with exponent dividing a positive integer $n$ is a $\mathbb Z/n \mathbb Z$ module. This, together with the structure theorem for finite abelian groups, givens plenty of examples. For instance,
$$
\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z \ncong \mathbb Z/n^2 \mathbb Z
$$
as $\mathbb Z/n^2\mathbb Z$-modules, but the two modules have the same cardinality.

Let us construct two modules over a finite ring $R$ having isomorphic group ($\mathbb Z$-module) structure but non-isomorphic $R$-module structure.
Let $R$ be a ring (not necessarily finite at this point) and $S=R[X]/(X^2)$.

The $R$-module $R^2$ is an $S$-module in two different ways: First $S\cong_R R^2$ gives a structure where $X(1,0)=(0,1)$ and $X(0,1)=(0,0)$. Second $S/(X)\cong R[X]/(X)$ induces an $S$-module structure on $R$. Taking a direct sum, we obtain another $S$-module structure on $R^2$ where now $X(1,0)=(0,0)$ and $X(0,1)=(0,0)$. The two $S$-module structures are different, as $X$ acts differently on them. However, the $R$-module structure is the same.
In particular, therefore also the module structure over the prime ring of $R$ is the same. However, this is simply the group structure. Taking $R$ a finite ring produces the desired example.